# Angular $http appears to make two server calls

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angulars $http to make calls to my backend services. I can't however figure out why the UI appears to make two calls to my services. I navigate to the Angular partial using ui-router like so

```
$stateProvider.state('new/client', {
        url: '/client/new',
        templateUrl: globalContextPath + '/javascripts/partials/modals/client/new.html',
        controller: 'NewClientModalController'
    })
```

Once in my partial and controller I initialize a bit of data.

```
var vm = this;

var retrieveServers = function () {
    AppServerFactory.list()
        .then(function (success) {
            $log.debug(success);
            vm.appServerList = success.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < vm.appServerList.length; i++) {
                if (vm.appServerList[i].defaultItem == true) {
                    vm.clientServers.push(vm.appServerList[i]);
                }
            }
        });
};

retrieveServers();
```

The factory function itself

```
factory.list = function () {
    return $http.get(globalContextPath + '/api/app-server/list');
};
```

Versioning:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "angularjs#~1.4.6",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4"
}
```

I've tried taking the route of just just using $http from my controller but it seems like no matter where I use $http throughout my app all calls are doubled to my backend - this is observed by looking at my hibernate queries always running twice when the front end hits my backend services. I believe to have ruled out the backend by using a soap client and not observing the same behavior. Suspicion point that I currently have - if I place a breakpoint in my functions it appears that a controller is loaded twice. I'm currently investigating if I'm using ui-router incorrectly but no luck yet. Curious if anyone has hints while I continue to stumble.

Comment: Please post your template's code.

Comment: You have probably declared ng-controller="NewClientModalController" in your template new.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too when I first began using ui-router, as I was defining the controller both in my routes and explicitly in the HTML. Is there any chance you defined it in the HTML as well?

Comment: welp - that was it! Thanks!